# What could be causing this error in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
  - (void) setConstrainedTransform: (CGAffineTransform) aTransform
{


    imageView.transform = aTransform;
    CGAffineTransform concat;
    CGSize asize = imageView.frame.size;

    if(asize.width > MAXZOOM * originalSize.width)
    {
        concat = CGAffineTransformConcat(imageView.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeScale((MAXZOOM * originalSize.width / asize.width), 1.0f));
        imageView.transform = concat;
    }
}
```

where `MAXZOOM` is defined as `2.0f`.

The problem is, it shows the following error:

> Expected ')' before ';' token;

I tried everything I could think of to solve it, but could not succeeded. Does anyone know what could be causing this error and how I could fix it?

Comment: Please use the code tags

Comment: what u mean by code tags

Comment: He means the button at the top of the editing field with curly braces. You can highlight all of your code, then click that button. It will make the code show up properly formatted. I already fixed this post, but now you'll know in the future.

Comment: Please put the define in the code snippet, too and also tell us where the error is reported (which line).

Comment: Have a look for errors on you #import files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you have defined the macro with a trailing semicolon?

```
//                  v
#define MAXZOOM 2.0f;
```

If so, remove that and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 4):

Just assuming: did you put a `;` at the end of the `#define` ?
Remove that, it will be put where you use `MAXZOOM`.

So instead of

```
#define MAXZOOM 2.0f;
```

make it

```
#define MAXZOOM 2.0f
```